# Un sens de « vouloir »

Tags: sens, verbes

> *Via Mala*, John Knittel
> Lauretz était un homme puissant, pesant beaucoup plus que sa taille n'aurait voulu.

Il ne semble pas exister un sens de « vouloir » répondant à l'utilisation de ce varbe qui a été faite dans la phrase de Knittel ci-dessus.

Si l'acception suivante trouvée au TLFi pourrait résulter en une utilisation légitime, le fait qu'elle est restreinte à un sujet qui est une chose rend cela impossible.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vouloir)) b) [Le suj. désigne une chose, un fait] Être le signe de quelque chose.

Apparemment, aucune autre définition du TLFI ne convient.

Quel sens donner à « vouloir  » dans ce contexte ?

Comment: Je pense qu'on nous dit que Lauretz n'est pas très grand pour son poids. Son poids n'est pas adapté à sa taille.

Comment: @MasB Il ne faudrait pas utiliser les commentaires pour des réponses,

Comment: il ne s'agissait que d'une hypothèse sans que j'aie un argument convaincant autre que mon intuition. C'est pourquoi je ne l'ai pas baptisée "Réponse".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'est traduit de l'[anglais](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&redir_esc=y&id=IsJAAAAAIAAJ&dq=Via%20Mala%2C%20John%20Knittel&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=heavy%20weight) :

> *Lauretz was a heavy man carrying much more weight than nature meant him to.*

La particule vaut pour « meant him to carry » par ellipse to verbe il me semble. Avec vouloir ça semble soit l'idée de *permettre/consentir*, soit l'idée d'*exiger par sa nature*. Peut-être que « ne l'aurait voulu » (*qu'il pèse/le voir peser*) aurait été plus clair ou cohérent ? Je ne suis pas certain de la formulation, à la première lecture la phrase me paraissait incomplète, alors qu'avec le complément elle me semble redondante...

Answer (score 0):

En fait il semble qu'il existe une définition qui convienne bien.

> ([TlFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vouloir)) b) Exiger de par sa nature, tendre à.

- Lauretz était un homme puissant, pesant beaucoup plus que sa taille ne l'aurait demandé.